# What's causing my npm install to throw an ERESOLVE error relating to karma-jasmine-html-reporter?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, node-modules

Can anyone please explain how to read this dependency error that I am getting while doing

`npm install`

And also how to resolve such dependency errors.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsojA.png)

I am using Angular 16, the latest stable version.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   jasmine-core@"^3.6.0" from karma-jasmine@4.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/karma-jasmine
npm ERR!     dev karma-jasmine@"~4.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer karma-jasmine@">=1.1" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!       dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.8" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: jasmine-core@5.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   peer jasmine-core@">=3.8" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!     dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to different causes:

If you have any of those packages installed in your package.json, you will need to upgrade them to a compatible version so that the conflicting package can be installed without problems.

It is possible that another package is installing as a dependency an older version of a package that then gives problems with another package you are trying to install in question. This case is more complicated, but it would be the same as in the previous case: upgrade the package to install new versions of the libraries it uses as dependencies, if possible.

It may also be due to an error with the npm cache. Sometimes it works by deleting your `node_modules` folder, using `npm cache clean --force` and then rerunning `npm install`.

Another solution (though not recommended) is to ignore these dependency warnings and run `npm install` with the `--force` option or the `--legacy-peer-deps` option. This will cause this warning to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, actually i have some packages in my application that haven't got any update since a long time. And all of them are till their latest version, but still throwing dependency error. So should I remove them and start looking for other packages with similar functionality?

Comment: @Piyush I would recommend yes. Also, if you are starting the project, it is easier to look for new packages than if it were a project already started, where it is much more difficult.